# If I up vote an answer that is negative, will the user still get the 10 points?

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

If an answer is say -5, and I up-vote it, will they still get the plus 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

From the [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You gain reputation when: [...] answer is voted up: +10

This applies regardless of the current score of the answer.

---

As for the help links not working, you might want to post that as a separate question and tag it [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), so that the people who handle bug reports are more likely to see it and deal with it. If it's an SE-wide problem for you and not just SFF, you could report it on [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) instead; this will increase the chances of those people seeing it.

Comment: Cheers I've reported the other issue